# Permanent Solution to : files, strings w/o \n mixing to command line

Tags: cat

file contains no newline terminator.

final line of file is mixed to the username in command prompt.

file:

```
line 1
```

test:

```
user /: cat file
line 1user /:
```

Solution is suggested to be : to add a new line terminator to file.

How can this solution be regarded as the proper thing ?

this means in the future a strage file can ruin our mood if it does not have a new line terminator.

Logic would suggest.. to not trust anything. but to be correct yourself.

So If I want to be correct.. I should never permit my username to show up at the end of some string regardless of it has a new line terminator or not.

I am not suppose to count on them.

I am suppose to be my own entity.

is there an alternative solution to ensure my username never becomes a victim of a "new-line-terminator-less" file or string ?

Perhaps solutions can not exist because it would make other things disfunctional such as "tail" and etc ?

but there has to be some logic.

looking for some logic.

Comment: @dhag, That question did not know the solution to the problem would be something that is not desired on a personal level. Turns out linux users are okay with that solution in that question. But it goes against my logic and standards. That is why I had to ask an expanded version with more specifics.

Comment: @dhag, consult to someone who has read both questions completely with proper level of understanding. it can in no way be considered a duplicate.

Comment: In Unix-based systems, a text file consists of lines _terminated_ by a newline character (not _separated_). So, by that definition, your file isn't a "text file", and you may as well `cat /bin/cat`

Comment: @Fox, well no matter how it is.. the prompt with username is not suppose to fall victim to it. prompt with username is like the "footer" equivalence". ( compared to web design etc.. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can this solution be regarded as the proper thing ?

Because the purpose of `cat` is actually not to display files. That's a side effect.

The purpose of `cat` is to *con**cat**enate* files (hence the name). It does so by reading each file in turn, and outputting the content of each to its standard output, which in turn can be redirected if so desired.

It is often useful to use `cat` to simply display the contents of a file, and that happens because by default, the standard output of a process is tied to the terminal. You can also use a dedicated pager, such as `less` or its older sibling `more`, to view files, as a pager is *intended* to be used for viewing files.

If `cat` terminated its output, or the content of each file, with a newline, that would break its longstanding contract. It would no longer be useful for actually concatenating files; if you were to take a large file, split it in parts, and re-concatenate the parts, using such a modified `cat`, the result would be something other than what you started with.

Remember that the UNIX philosophy is for each tool to do some small thing, do it well, and do it in such a way that different tools can be combined to form larger contexts. That's why I can do something like ssh'ing to a remote host to execute a command, pipe the output of the ssh session into a local tool (awk, perl, grep, whatever) to massage the output, and pipe the result of that into, say, `lpr` to get a hard-copy printout or `less` to browse through with the ability to scroll back and forth. It's all stdout to stdin with tools where every tool does only one thing, and most of the simple tools (and many of the not-so-simple tools) either follow this pattern by default or can be made to follow that pattern with appropriate command-line parameters.

> is there an alternative solution to ensure my username never becomes a victim of a "new-line-terminator-less" file or string ?

Yes, of course. Set your prompt to begin with a newline, as illustrated by the below.

```
$ printf 'hello' > $TMP/hello
$ PS1='\u \W: '
michael ~: cat $TMP/hello
hellomichael ~: PS1='\n\u \W: '

michael ~: cat $TMP/hello
hello
michael ~:
```